# Which drive had a "journal commit I/O error"?

Tags: linux, io, journaling, dmesg

I received a message:

```
kernel:[123456.789012] journal commit I/O error
```

Which disk drive had the [journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) error?

Answer (score 1):

Search dmesg output for the timestamp value:

```
dmesg|grep -A 10 905494.178634
```

10 is the number of lines to show after the match.  Increase if needed.  It should start with something like:

```
[123456.789012] journal commit I/O error
[123456.789042] EXT3-fs (dm-1): error: ext3_put_super: Couldn't clean up the journal
```

You can identify that it's the same event because the timestamp is very close.  In this case, it's a dm (device mapper) disk, but I think for normal drives it would show sda1 or similar.

To find out which drive this really is, do:

```
sudo e2label dm-1
```

This only works if you use a label (if not, add one to all your drives for the future).  If it weren't in the ext* family, you would have to use a different label command.